# C++ reference and enum?

Tags: c++, enums, reference

I came across the code below, and the output is '2', I'm not familiar with enum and references, can somebody help me understand why the output is '2', thanks!

```
#include<iostream.h> 
enum bix
{
    a=1, b, c
};
int main()
{
    int x = c;
    int &y = x;
    int &z = x;
    y = b;
    cout<< z--;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Maybe ask a more focused question.

Comment: Both `y` and `z` *references* the same variable `x`, so changing either `y` or `z` will change `x`. And printing either `y` or `z` will print the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a value for an enumerator, then its value is one more than the previous one, or zero if it's the first. So the enumerators are

```
a=1, b=2, c=3
```

References are aliases for variables; doing something to a reference is exactly the same as doing it to the variable it refers to. `y` and `z` are aliases for `x`, so the code using them is equivalent to the same code using just `x`:

```
int x = 3;   // c is 3
x = 2;       // y is x, b is 2
cout << x--; // z is x; print the value (2) then decrement.
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike! It is the specification for non-value enumerator member part, now I get it, thank you so much!